# What is a programming language which is appropriate with data classification project

Tags: information-retrieval

I would like to easily implement a data classification project, so I'm looking for the language which provides the library for that. Could you suggest the proper language?

Comment: Maybe you'd better provide some more information: size of the data sets you are going to handle, operating system, some examples of the operations you might want to implement, some links to examples...

Comment: I believe your best option here is going to be ALGOL. Until you give more detail, I'll stand by that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(A little late coming, but I thought this answer should be here for the record).

[WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) and [MALLET](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/) are two useful libraries for data classification that I've come across. I've used WEKA in a couple of projects and can say that it is pretty mature. Both these libraries are Java-based.

Answer (score 2):

matlab is not exactly a programming language, but no doubt it's the easiest way to implementing math oriented programs. it has lots of toolboxes for classifications (e.g. MLP, SVM) optimization toolboxes.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Python distribution called [SciPy](http://www.scipy.org/) that has lots of tools for scientific programming and people have [used it to do data classification](http://machc.blogspot.com/2009/03/principle-component-analysis-in-python.html). Some bioinformatics people have built [Excel2SVM](http://www.bioinformatics.org/Excel2SVM/) in Python.

If the focus of your work is on the data classification, not on developing software, then Python is a good choice because you can be more productive than with languages like java or C++.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say you really need more information before choosing a language.

Where are you getting data from, what front end do you want to use (web / dedicated client) ?

C# could do just as good a job, or any Object oriented language.

Cheers

Comment: I agree. I like how Moddy answered the OP with a response that is just as silly as the question, and others are actually voting him down, but responding with "THIS toolset is the BEST!!"... all while knowing nothing about the requirements. wish I could +5 you.